# Как в android получить телефонный номер звонящего человека?

Tags: android

Мне в моем приложении программно считать телефонный номер, того человека, который мне звонит. Как это сделать? В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Не удалось повторить, не выводит ничего (

Answer (score 10):

Cоздаете класс, который наследуете от    `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "CustomBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();

    telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
        Log.v(TAG, "phoneNr: "+phoneNr);
}
}
```

Создаете такой класс:

```
public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber){



        switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        Log.d(TAG, "RINGING");
                        Log.v(TAG, "WE ARE INSIDE!!!!!!!!!!!");
                        Log.v(TAG, incomingNumber);
                        break;
        }       
}
```

Дальше в манифесте дописываете:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
...
<receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />     
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

И теперь при входящем звонке в лог выведется номер звонящего

Answer (score 2):

Тоже столкнулся с такой нуждой. У вас код избыточен. Этот номер пакуется системой в intent, который прилетает в метод onReceive. Получить сам номер можно так:

```
public class PhoneStateListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String inComingStringNumber;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            inComingStringNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(сontext, inComingStringNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Конечно, приемник не забываем прописать в манифесте, а приложению дать права на чтение статуса телефонной линии. Но гуглится это уже намного проще и описано выше.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ автора:*

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("incomingNumber : "+incomingNumber);
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

и

```
<receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```